# Stopping periodically running AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

## See *Update* section below for my modified solution

---

## Goal

- To poll URL periodically (e.g. every 30 seconds), but only when activity is in foreground
- Stop the polling if activity is not in foreground

## Periodical execution

- Handler object receiving Runnable object via the `postDelayed` method
- In the `run` method of the Runnable object AsyncTask is started
- In `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask the `postDelayed` of the Handler object is called again
- In `onResume` of the activity, `post` method of the Handler object is called
- In `onPause` of the activity, `removeCallbacks` of the Handler object is called to remove pending posts of the Runnable in the message queue

## Issue with cancelling of the polling

- Even though I remove the pending posts of Runnable in `onPause`, it can still happen that the currently running AsyncTask that executes its `doInBackground` method adds new Runnable to the queue when its `onPostExecute`is started (basically few moments later after the `removeCallbacks` was called in `onPause`)

## How I solve it right now

- boolean member variable `shouldPoll` was added to the activity
- it is set to true in `onResume`, and to false in `onPause`
- In `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask I check if the `shouldPoll` is true and call the `postDelayed` of the Handler object only in that case

## Concerns

- Is using the `shouldPoll` variable OK?
- I'm bit worried whether something can't happen to the activity (and thus the `shouldPoll` variable) in rare cases; therefore, somehow breaking the logic of the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`

## Source code snippets

### MainActivity

```
boolean shouldPoll = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    shouldPoll = true;
    handler.post(pollURLRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    shouldPoll = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(pollURLRunnable);
    super.onPause();
}

final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable pollURLRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        PollingAsyncTask pollTimestampAsyncTask = new PollingAsyncTask();
        pollTimestampAsyncTask.execute();
    }
};
```

### AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    if (result != null) {
        //Do something here
    }
    if (shouldPoll) {
        handler.postDelayed(pollURLRunnable, 10000);
    }
}
```

## Update

### MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.post(startIntentServiceRunnable);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(statusBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.MY_INTENT_FILTER));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(startIntentServiceRunnable);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(statusBroadcastReceiver);        
    super.onPause();
}

final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable startIntentServiceRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PollingService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
};


final BroadcastReceiver statusBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //...
        //Do something useful with the extras from intent here
        //...
        handler.postDelayed(startIntentServiceRunnable, 2000);
    }
};
```

### PollingService

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //...
    //Perform the polling and prepare results here
    //...
    broadcastResults();

}

private void broadcastResults() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.MY_INTENT_FILTER);
    //...
    //Fill the intent extras with the data here
    //...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: Use an `IntentService`. Keep the handler the way you have it, just broadcast the intent to start the service when it need it to download. Also do you need to use polling? It drains battery and generally is inefficient. Look into using Google Cloud Messaging or XMPP to push from your url to the phone.

Comment: I updated my original post with solution based on your suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot use push, because the URL is provided by 3rd party that doesn't know anything about GCM or XMPP. Let's say the solution with the IntentService is not most efficient, but sufficient ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the AsyncTask by making the hander run in a background thread. Then just move the work to the runnable you post to the handler.

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("Background thread");
    handlerThread.start();
    handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In the end, I decided to go with IntentService suggested by Rarw, but your suggestion seems like viable alternative too (at least to me). That's nice and sometimes also frustrating for me on Android development. I, not an Android expert, can't be sure if I picked the correct way of how to solve something from the multiple options that I can think of. In such cases, I end up with doubts if some hidden problems don't occur under some rare circumstances. ... but no-one said it will be an easy journey ;-)

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of programming. Where your code from 6 months ago always seems quaint and overly redundant. :)